# How to get the Percentage symbol in cell while calculating using pandas or any python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have data-frame below where I am taking the previous month data and getting the percentage.

[image: Data Frame]

Output which I get with the percentage is below:

code:

```py
current = df['August']
previous = df['September']

per=[]
for a, b in zip(current, previous):
    try:
        per.append(round((((a - b) / a) * 100.0)))
    except ZeroDivisionError:        
        per.append(0)
```

output

```
[0, 25, 54, 0, 0, 0, -22, 100, 0, 0, 38, 0, 100, -117, 0, 0, 100, 1, 0, -377, 37]
```

Expecting output along with "%" symbol like:

```
[0%, 25%, 54%, 0%, 0%, 0%, -22%, 100%, 0%, 0%, 38%, 0%, 100%, -117%, 0%, 0%, 100%, 1%, 0%, -377%, 37%]
```

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add "%" to your `float`, it needs to be converted into `str`

So, my suggestion is:

```
for a, b in zip(current, previous):
    try:
        #Add this two new lines
        x = repr((a - b) / a * 100.0)
        per.append(x + "%")
        #Do not need this
        #per.append(round((((a - b) / a) * 100.0)))
    except ZeroDivisionError:        
        per.append(0)
```

print out `print(per)` Yields:

```
['50.0%']
```

Comment: If you're going through the process of string conversion anyway, just format it as a percent. `f'{(b - a) / a:.2%}'`

Comment: Thanks a ton Alberto,

But the here I have finding an challenge to merge as well.

Comment: Happy to help @Sidh. On the other hand I'm sorry but I don't get it what's the next challenge you found. If you could help me to understand I could help :)